# Risk of unquoted bash parameters/variables

Tags: linux, bash, security, sudo

I recently read that it is dangerous to use unquoted parameter in bash scripts. I know that escaping is vital when it comes to SQL queries, but I don't see any problems with the following code (except for the obvious directory traversal)

```
#!/bin/bash

MYDIR="/tmp/$1"

if [ -d $MYDIR ] ; then
    /bin/rmdir $MYDIR
fi
```

Are the quotes in the assignment line already enough?

The only thing that seems to be possible is that the "if" line says

```
# ./mm.sh "arg1 arg2"
./mm.sh: line 5: [: /tmp: binary operator expected
```

But that does not seem very dangerous to me. Is there anything I missed?

**Edit:** To be more specific. Is there any way I can elevate my privileges when I run this using `sudo mm.sh`?

Regards,

Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rmdir` refuses to remove non-empty directories, so it's unlikely that your script has any really catastrophic effects. Still you might try to figure out what happens when you call

```
./mm.sh ' -o -n /home/lukas/xyz'
```

Comment: Nothing special here: /bin/rmdir: invalid option -- 'o'
Try `/bin/rmdir --help' for more information.

Comment: The point being, the given argument still allowed the condition to evaluate to true, allowing `rmdir` to be run with a nonsensical string of arguments. Quoting `$MYDIR` would have prevented that.

Comment: I agree. That is serious enough. I'm actually wondering if I can elevate my rights when this is run using sudo.

Comment: Try playing with an argument like: `./mm.sh ' $(rm -f /tmp/bar)'`. This may not cause trouble; I've not formally tested it. But the mere fact that your script is not working on the files it is told to work on is a major problem — include the double quotes.

Comment: @fr00tyl00p Yes, in this particular case, nothing bad happens, since `rmdir`, at least the GNU version, stops as soon as it encounters the `-o` option. Replace the `rmdir` in your script by `rm -rf --` and it's no longer harmless. For extra fun, try it as root, let's say, with `./mm.sh ' -o -n /'`. **(DON'T!)**

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Parameter expansion `$MYDIR` and command substitution `$(rm -f /tmp/bar)` happen in parallel, not sequentially. The result of parameter expansion is not subject to command substitution afterwards, therefore your example does not cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

ok, what if you have a directory `/tmp/foo bar` with space(s)?

if you pass argument in this way, without quote: `./mm.sh foo bar`

your script will check `/tmp/foo` and if you really have a `/tmp/foo`, it would be removed, which is not what you want.

dangerous doesn't always mean something would be deleted unexpectedly. If you don't quote, your script will parse and use your parameter wrongly. It may stop running, like your example, and it may run, but incorrectly. Think about if your script generates an important report, but incorrectly. isn't it dangerous?

Comment: You are right. I should have been more specific. I mean security issues that may occur when you run this by sudo for example.